# Stata: reshape wide data if data is mi set

Tags: stata, reshape

My data is in long format with an individual identifier and a year identifier.
It is a merged and appended data-file from different data-sets.

Edit:
*My goals is to reshape it to run a regression on all observations from one year, with variables from previous years. 
I'm not aiming to be able to use any `mi` commands whatsoever.*

This is my reshape-code:

```
use "${DATA_PATH}HViD_SOEP_rev_dum.dta"

* save all variable-names
quietly describe, varlist
local all_vars = r(varlist) 
display "`all_vars'"
 ** reshape **
foreach var in `all_vars'{
    display "`var'"
    * no reshape for pid, hid, syear and ypnat 
    if `var' == "pid" | `var' == "hid" | `var' == "syear" | `var' == "ypnat*" {
        * do nothing
    }
    else{
        * reshape 
        reshape wide `var', i(pid) j(syear)
    }
}
```

I get the return

> no; data are mi set
>   Use mi reshape to perform reshape on these data.  mi reshape has the same syntax as reshape.
>    Perhaps you did not type reshape. In that case, the command you typed calls reshape and it is not appropriate for use with mi data.  Use mi extract or mi xeq to select the data on which you want to run the command, which is probably m=0

In the stata-manual one reads:

> mi unset is a rarely used command to unset the data. Better alternatives include mi extract and
>   mi export (see [MI] mi extract and [MI] mi export, respectively).

I tried `mi extract = 0` which was recommended [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/316757-reshape-issue). 
But the return was

> syntax error
>       m=0 found where # expected

I also tried `mi reshape wide`var', i(pid) j(syear)`. Which resolved in

> mi reshape wide pgtatzt, i(pid) j(syear)
>   (imputed variables brutto1 brutto2 hinc imo geld betr netw erbey unregistered because not in m=0)
>   _mi_miss not found

So, now i'm pretty out of options. I do't know where to find the mi_miss variable as it is not in the original data.

I don't want to export my data to a csv-file because that would result in loosing my labels.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your data are set up for multiple imputation, meaning that there are extra copies of the original data with missing values imputed. Do you intend to do do an analysis of the imputed data?  Or, do you wish to recover the original data set?

Comment: I intend to use the imputed data in a regression as right-hand variables.

Comment: This should go to Statalist.  You did make two syntax errors- using `reshape` instead of `mi reshape` and using `mi extract = 0` instead of the correct `mi extract 0`, which would have left you without any imputed data, the goal of the post you linked to.    The rest depends on details of your data and on seeing  a complete listing of the Stata log after `mi reshape`,  and cannot be answered without further investigation.

Comment: When  posting in Statalist, 1) show the results of  `mi reshape` on a few variables first, rather than attempt a wholesale conversion; exclude those in the "unregistered" list; 2) Use `mi describe` to see how the variables in the "unregistered" message are characterized. Be sure to read the FAQ, especially FAQ 12.

Comment: Yes. I posted the original code as it was before finding out that the data was mi set. As I said, both commands `mi extract 0` and `mi reshape` result in
> _mi_miss not found
. 
I also read the FAQ regarding mi-data. At the time i asked my question i still thought there would be some way of regaining _mi_miss or there was a specific problem i just did not understand(i had never heart of mi data before).

Comment: It seems i wasn't quite clear with my question. I edited it and hope that my goal is now clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the time and thought you gave into the problem. 
I will answer my question because I found at least a workaround. I'm aware that my problem is a very specific one. Anyway, imho, [this is the best way to solve the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com).

The original idea comes from [statalist](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/316757-reshape-issue).

I exported the mi set data to .csv and made sure that labeled variables where exported not as integers but as values. 
I then reimported the data to stata. The resulting file is not mi set anymore. 
By appending this data to the rest of my data i regained the target-file, but this time it is not mi set. 
I made sure that the reimported file was NOT the master file, but the using file, when appending. 
Thus, the labels from the master-file will be expanded to the final file.
Here is my code for exporting and reimporting:

```
* load data *
use "${DATA_PATH}HViD_green_yellow.dta"

*** export data to .csv ***  
/* 
NOTE: instead of labels the numeric values are saved! This is important to 
ensure that the reimported dataset will be compatabile with SOEP-data.  
All strings are in double quotes: ""
*/
export delimited using "${DATA_PATH}HViD_miunset.csv", nolabel quote replace

clear  

*** import data ***
import delimited "${DATA_PATH}HViD_miunset.csv"

*** check data for integrity **
cf _all using "${DATA_PATH}HViD_green_yellow.dta"

*** save data ***
save "${DATA_PATH}HViD_miunset.dta"
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete, as it does not result in a data set of the proper size that will accept an `mi` command. I've provided an example that demonstrates the problem. Post a solution based on this example that includes the steps you've omitted.

Comment: I don't think that the proper solution here is a dataset that accepts any `mi` commands. The goal is a dataset that can be reshaped, whether with `mi reshape` or `reshape`.

Comment: You said in response to my comment to your original post that your goal was not to recover the original data, but to analyze the imputed data. The problem you faced is that one of the _mi variables is not present in the data set so that a proper imputed analysis is impossible.  I assumed when you said you'd found a solution that you had found a way of doing this, which would be very interesting if true.

Comment: If that wasn't your intention, then I apologize. Unfortunately, you won't be able to properly analyze the imputed data. The whole point of multiple imputation is that the analysis will  incorporate  variance due to the replication.   If  you analyze the combined data (original +  replicates) without _mi_,  the sample size will be(1 + # replicates)  x the original sample size, which will give bad standard errors.
If it were my data, I would try to obtain the  correct  imputation dataset or redo the imputations myself, preferably after obtaining a copy of the authors' imputation models.

Comment: Actually, given that you have some mi information in the dataset, your best bet is to examine the data and construct an `mi import` statement (doesn't require presence of _mi_miss).  If you wish to do this, start a discussion on Statalist.  Otherwise,  to get the original data with no imputation replicates, look for the variable _mi_m and
`keep if _mi_m ==0`.  Then `drop _mi*`.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight! I know that this goes eventually beyond the scope of the comment-section but still...: 
Isn't avery imputation "just" one more variable and i take the mean of the regressions as the result-value?
Eg. if i'd do a regression with imputed variables on each side and, say, 5 imputations, I'd take the mean of the results as reported result?

Comment: Also: I edited out the `append`- part to evade further cunfusion on this part.

Comment: The final estimates are indeed averages of the estimates for the replicates.  However if you fail to `mi set` the data and use `mi estimate`, the you get standard errors that are ~ 44% of the correct size (= 1/sqrt(5)), because you are analyzing a dataset 5 x larger than actual.  Just multiplying standard errors by sqrt(5) won't correct this, because the computation ignores the component of variance due to imputation.  I suggest that you read the introductory sections of the MI manual and ask further questions on Statalist.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to replicate the posted solution based on the "simple example" on pp 18-20 of the Stata MI manual. To do this, I've deleted  the variable _mi_miss, the cause of the failure of your `mi reshape` command.   <s>As can be seen, the result of applying your code is not a data set of proper size that will accept an `mi` command. Please post a working version of your solution based on this example.</s> . **Edit** I've added a command which might  recover only the original data set before imputation. This assumes that the variable `_mi_m`, which is the replication counter, is still in the dataset.

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/mheart5, clear
mi set mlong
mi register imputed age bmi
set seed 29390
mi impute mvn age bmi = attack smokes hsgrad female, add(10)

/* Replicate Post Problem */
drop _mi_miss
save  green_yellow, replace
sum attack smokes _mi*
export delimited unset.csv, nolabel quote replace
clear
import delimited unset.csv, clear
cf _all using green_yellow
keep if _mim_m==0   // ADDED
save unset, replace
```

Comment: Why do you `append using unset`?
After the import of `unset.csv` you have already reached my goal: a dataset which is not `mi set` anymore but is in any other way identical to the old one (except of course for the labels).

Comment: I was just trying to copy your solution, in which you stated: 
" At the end it is important that the reimported data is not the active dataset. You then gave the statement:


`append using "${DATA_PATH}HViD_miunset.dta", gen(origin)`

Comment: Ah. Im sorry. I append the `mi set` data to a completly different dataset. Not to itself. 
As stated in my question 
> It is a merged and appended data-file from different data-sets. 
The (originally) `mi set` data is just one of many datasets. It is appended as the last step towards my final dataset. 
I'll edit this.

Comment: Okay, I understand.  I'll remove the last append in my example, then show the command that should recover the original data set without imputed values.

Comment: I see now why your solution seems to work: the last data set appended will inherit the value labels of variables in the data appended to.  However, as I said in another comment. the "unset" data is not pure.  It will include the original data with missing values + replicates with imputed values. Assume that the original data is in `flong` form, that the original data had n observations,  that  n_m  of them had  imputed values and that there are k replicates. Then the size of the "unset" dataset will be n + k n_m.

Comment: To the point of labels: Yes, exactly. 
To the question of observations: 
Hmm. I didn't do the imputation. But in my dataset every observation has k = 5 replications. Regardless if there is a missing value in the original data or not.

Comment: I can't tell whether there were replicates in all the datasets or just the one you imported. See the end of my example for one way to drop all the replicates, assuming that the variable `_mi_m` exists: `keep if _mi_m==0` .